# What is wrong with this C code?

Tags: c

I am following head first C book and now I am following the string theory part. There was a program written that return the track no and the full name of the track when a part of the track's name is searched and is found out. But the code is not working properly. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
"I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
"Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
"Dancing with a Dork",
"From here to maternity",
"The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i5;i++){
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)){
        printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);}
    }

}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a possibility that the newline may be included in the input with `fgets`.

Comment: Not sure if a typo or the actual code, but on your `for` loop, it should be `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`

Comment: for(i=0;i5;i++){     change  i<=5

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/4142924).

Comment: Your very next step should be to learn how to use your debugger.  It is an essential tool that you must become good at using before you can progress:)

Comment: change find track function to void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=15;i++){
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)){
        printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
        return;
        }
    }
    
 printf("Track Not found");

}

Comment: @EsmaeelE why `i <= 15`? `i < 5` is perfectly fine. I strongly believe that the `i` error is a typo otherwise the program wouldn't even compile. The real problem was pointed by Weather Vane and BLUEPIXY.

Comment: @woz Yes this is a typo i correct it in my edit proposal to Question.

Comment: Apart from the typo, the program doesn't works correctly

Comment: @proneon add this: `search_for[strcspn(search_for, "\n")] = 0;` before calling `find_track(search_for);` on your `main` function. It's the solution based on Weather Vane's comment.

Comment: @proneon the program works properly after correcting the typo and removing the newline from the input string.

Comment: @EsmaeelE Your edit introduced a logic bug and also caused mismatched curly braces.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I correct curly brace. what is the logic bug?

Comment: @EsmaeelE The array has 5 elements. The loop condition should be `i < 5` because the valid indices are 0..4

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes thanks for catching my mistake!

Comment: @EsmaeelE One last thing, just in my opinion adding the `return` and `printf` go beyond fixing a typo into changing the author's intent. They might want to see multiple matches.

Comment: @And by change it we must catch  condition of this string not found, for example by defining a flag or etc.

Comment: One of the things that's wrong with it is that you didn't read the directions on how to ask a good question.  What testing have you done?  In what way does it not function properly?  What are you expecting the output to be and why?

Comment: I find out the fgets() function that is not work true in this example. if i try to search with constant string that i put in hard coding in source "search string" strstr works good

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find out using `fgets()` is the cause of error in getting user input and use this string on `strstr()` function.

By perform some good advice from Blastfurnace, woz and other guys in Question comment section I can fix this problem.

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
"I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
"Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
"Dancing with a Dork",
"From here to maternity",
"The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    char * pch;
    int flag = 0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        pch = strstr(tracks[i], search_for);
        if (pch){
            printf("find in Track   %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
            flag = 1;//find

        }
    }
    
    if (flag == 0)// not found
        printf("Track Not found\n");

}

int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fscanf (stdin, "%s", search_for);
    find_track(search_for);
     
    return 0;
}
```